# What is $B(N)$ crystal structure? What does this nomenclature stand for

Tags: solid-state-physics, terminology, definition, crystals

Is it basic cubic with 20 atoms?

I can't find the explanation for this nomenclature online. Maybe I could find it in a textbook, but if someone answers it here, other people can just google it.

Comment: A little context would help.

Comment: Skyrmion hexagonal lattices appear in B20 crystals (MnSi type).

Comment: As a hint: A20 is alpha Uranium’s crystal structure under the Strukturebericht (probably misspelled) system. Then the B prefix instead of A is an ordered alloy version of the structure, with MnSi as the prototype.

Comment: @JonCuster Thanks! It was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Strukturbericht designations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strukturbericht_designation) are one of several categorizations of crystal structures, going back to the early 1900s. "A" compounds are one element, with A1 being fcc, A2 is bcc, and A3 is hcp. A20 is the structure of $\alpha$-U, belonging to the Cmcm space group.

The "B" compounds are compounds of two elements with equal numbers. Thus B1 is NaCl, B2 is CsCl, and B3 is zincblende.

B20 has the prototype of FeSi, with the P$2_{1}3$ space group.